# How to unbind the autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using this  [autocomplete plugin](http://mabp.kiev.ua/content/source/autocomplete/autocomplete.html). My problem was how to unbind and bind new one.

Please check this sample code: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DdqCu/1/)

When I select any element in auto suggestion I need to call that autocomplete function again but here my problem is coming as twice. I am unable to unbinds

I try with unautocomplete, unbind and destroy but its not working.

Comment: Is this solves your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/Er2pP/

Comment: thanks for your reply but same problem exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/DdqCu/3/
I've added `$("#testid").unbind();` to the onSelect handler.